# Adding Columns into single line with out header R

Tags: r

I have a data as like this

```
  Animal  Bird  Else
  E_01    S_ed  14.56
  W_3     Asw   sqc
```

And I just need to add all the columns without header as single line

```
  E_01      
  W_3        
  S_ed
  Asw
  14.56
  sqc
```

The problem is  each time the data and header will change. so I can not depend the header. Which function will help to solve this puzzle

Comment: What data type do you want to output? A character vector, or a one column data frame, or just write this data to a file with one value per line?

Comment: data frame @Calum You